# fetch() failed, but request is not reaching the server, "Object2 not itterable"

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch-api

I have been using this for fetching images, but there is an error continuously logging but I can't get any solution please help. The request is also not reaching the backend for some reason. The Error code received is 422. The same code is working fine with others but not on my side for some reason, I even tried axios but the problem still persists.

```
import axios from 'axios';
var FormData = require('form-data');
// Next.js API route support: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction

export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: {
            sizeLimit: '5mb', // Set desired value here
        },
    },
};
async function uploadFile(
    prompt,
    withoutbg_image_base64,
    randID,
    username,
    model_name
) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('prompt', prompt);
    formData.append('withoutbg_image_base64', withoutbg_image_base64);
    formData.append('randID', randID);
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('model_name', model_name);
    
    try {
        const response = await fetch(URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });

        const data = await response.json();

        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    return {};
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that show's how you are calling the method and also share the portion from server side code where you are handling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution it's the node version the above code is compatible with v16 but not with v18. Hope anyone having such a problem this would help you.